# Security between Google App Engine projects

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I ensure that only a specific Google App Engine project can communicate with another web endpoint located in an other GAE Project.

I want to lock communication between App Engine Projects.

What would be the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to make use of the request header `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` within your  App Engine web endpoint application to assert the identity of your specific App Engine app that should be allowed to communicate. This header is added to the request by the URLFetch service and is not user modifiable.

Detail documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/#Python_Asserting_identity_to_other_App_Engine_apps

Comment: What if some other app which is not on app engine add fake header to request?

Comment: @iamgopal AFAIK, App Engine will [sanitize or amends request headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_Request_headers) and it looks to be guarantee to be there if the request is generated via Another [App Engine Application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/#Python_Asserting_identity_to_other_App_Engine_apps)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I thought application itself is admin, so how about like this?

1. Add `login: admin` to all handlers in `app.yaml`
2. Go to [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com), project -> Permissions, then Add **project account** which you want to communicate with into **service accounts**.

I hope it works.